# A more elegant approach to a generic type conversion function

Tags: c#, type-conversion

A generic function is expected to take a boxed (`object`) value and cast it to specified type (within reasonable).
The following works, but looks bad (both the code and resulting IL) and ends up boxing-unboxing for nothing (since compiler disagrees to implicitly cast a primitive to a generic type):

```
static T convert<T>(object val) {
    var t = typeof(T);
    if (t == typeof(int)) {
        if (val is int) return (T)val;
        if (val is double) return (T)(object)(int)(double)val;
        if (val is float) return (T)(object)(int)(float)val;
        if (val is bool) return (T)(object)((bool)val ? 1 : 0);
    } else if (t == typeof(double)) {
        if (val is double) return (T)val;
        if (val is float) return (T)(object)(double)(float)val;
        if (val is int) return (T)(object)(double)(int)val;
        if (val is bool) return (T)(object)((bool)val ? 1.0 : 0.0);
    } else if (t == typeof(float)) {
        if (val is float) return (T)val;
        if (val is double) return (T)(object)(float)(double)val;
        if (val is int) return (T)(object)(float)(int)val;
        if (val is bool) return (T)(object)((bool)val ? 1f : 0f);
    } else if (t == typeof(bool)) {
        if (val is bool) return (T)val;
        if (val is double) return (T)(object)((double)val != 0.0);
        if (val is float) return (T)(object)((float)val != 0f);
        if (val is int) return (T)(object)((int)val != 0);
    } else return (T)val;
    throw new Exception($"Can't convert ${val} to ${typeof(T)}");
}
```

Context: an external library implements generalized function/closure wrappers through a class like this

```cs
class Function {
    public Function(int argCout) { ... }
    public object invoke_0() { ... }
    public object invoke_1(object v0) { ... }
    public object invoke_2(object v0, object v1) { ... }
    // and so on...
}
```

that you inherit from, like so:

```
class MyFunc : Function {
    public MyFunc() : base(1) {}
    public override object invoke_1(object v0) {
        // (... cast v0 to appropriate type and call the destination function)
    }
}
```

Rest assured, it does not take me very long to realize that:

- Although fairly efficient, it is hard to organize multiple tiny classes since they are going to be some distance away from their use in code (can't declare a class mid-expression).
- C# is rather unforgiving about type mismatches when unboxing (e.g. trying to unbox a float as a double will throw an exception).

So I decide to do a few generic wrappers like this:

```cs
class WrapAction<T> : Function {
    Action<T> action;
    public MyFunc(Action<T> act) : base(1) {
        action = act;
    }
    public override object invoke_1(object v0) {
        action.Invoke(WrapHelpers.convert<T>(v0));
        return null;
    }
}
```

(where `WrapHelpers.convert` is the function demonstrated in the beginning of the question).

As this allows to do

```cs
Function fun = new WrapAction<string>((str) => Console.WriteLine(str));
```

instead.

Other notes:

- Switching `object` to `dynamic` allows to hide some unboxing operations, but otherwise is not helpful.
- Creating different `convert` versions/overloads for different target types allows to eliminate some checking at cost of added line count (as your delegate now has to accept arguments as `objects` before unboxing them via one or other function).

Comment: Have you tried to use [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: As a side note, if `val` is always a boxed value type, constrain `T` to value types and remove the `object` case, its nonsensical; why would you call `convert<object>` if you already have an `object` to begin with?

Comment: The sole purpose of object-case was to allow a non-specific argument type in a generic wrapper shown later, though the mention made me realize that I could very well explicit-cast in the final else-block (as if the conversion fails, that's the same as the `throw` below). Fortunately, since I now know Convert.ChangeType exists, this code will go on unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sidestep all the issues related to unboxing to the exact type of the objet using the static class `System.Convert` that leverages the `IConvertible` interface and avoids casts altoghether.

This, as you well note, will fail at runtime:

```
object o = (short)1;
var i = (iny)o; //runtime exception
```

But this won't:

```
object o = (short)1;
var i = Convert.ToInt32(o); //calls IConvertible.ToInt32 explicitly implemented in System.Int16
```

That alone can improve the code of your `convert` method quite a bit; you don't have to go through all the possible types that can be boxed for each target type.

The good news is that you can still improve that drastically more if you add to the mix the general `Convert.ChangeType` method Pavel points out in his commetary above. This method already has all the plumbing to figure out how to do the conversion if possible (you might be trying to reinvent the wheel here):

```
static T convert<T>(object val)  =>
    (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof(T))
```

It's important to note that there can be some semantic differences if you use `Convert` instead of your code. Yours will truncate decimal values when converting to an integral numeric type, `Convert` will round. If this can be an issue, then you might have to stick to your code in some scenarios.

Comment: Thank you! `Convert.ChangeType` is just the thing I was looking for. Rounding behaviour is acceptable, I think this reduces the work to forbidding a few unusual conversions (like string->int).